# Cannot get mod_rewrite to work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mamp

I have searched for hours to try to find a solution.  I must be missing something.  I'm trying to clean up my urls.

I'm having my index page generate pages based on an action.  Basically:

```
    <?php
include("header.htm");
$action = $_GET['action'];
$action = basename($action);

if (!empty($_GET['action'])) {
    if (file_exists("$action.htm")
} else {
    include("index.htm");
}
include("footer.htm");
?>
```

I am using MAMP and Mod_rewrite is running when I look at phpInfo.

I created a new .htaccess file in the same folder as my index.php from above. I used bad code to see if it threw an error, and it did, so I know it's being referenced.  Here is exactly what I have in it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/galleries$ /?action=galleries
</IfModule>
```

I have changed every httpd.conf file to AllowOverride all for the directory.

I see an abundance of people having this issue but have still not found what I am missing.  Please help?